# ''Cannot parse result path string:" Error in android studio version 4.0.0,

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I am just running a simple hello world example in android studio 4.0.0 . it gives me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform core-1.1.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cd4879837b92e15e5ff5501be1c5771e\core-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                       
   > Failed to transform constraintlayout-solver-1.1.3.jar (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-incremental-desugaring-v2=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\morteza\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.constraintlayout\constraintlayout-solver\1.1.3\54abe9ffb22cc9019b0b6fcc10f185cc4e67b34e\constraintlayout-solver-1.1.3.jar.
         > Cannot parse result path string:                                  

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 17s
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
```

here's my project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app_3"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

i did nothing especial, just create a new project with EmptyActivity. i don't have any idea, please let me know if any additional information is needed. thank you

Comment: change the minimum sdk to 19

Comment: Try remove spaces from android studio and project path

Comment: tnx a lot @Reza, it solved my problem after more than 3 days effort, many tnx

Comment: by the way, what was the problem with minSdk 16?

Answer (score 1):

Can you update the gradle file with Java 8 compatibility

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Also you might need to enable multiDexSupport

```
multiDexEnabled true //add this line in the defaultConfig
```

Comment: tnx a lot for responding. the problem is solved by changing minSdk to 19, but i am so curious about the options you proposed. first i have the question that my jdk version is 14, does it related to the version you are talking about?

Comment: From Gradle 3.4, you need Java 8 and above and also the gradle task "app:mergeExtDexDebug" I thought there might be something to do with multiDex Support.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#j8-library-desugaring